# doesn't have a default value | Laravel

Tags: laravel

En Postman tengo lo siguiente en post:

```
{
  "name":"Alex",
  "surname":"Carrion",
  "email":"alex@victor.com",
  "password":"alex"
}
```

me arroja esto:

> Illuminate\Database\QueryException: SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1364 Field 'email' doesn't have a default value (SQL: insert into `users` (`name`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values ($2y$04$50Wrw1RlVwcs9wsnl4CTJugtcsNEfC..rSm6dAh5pbC/e7sQdGSDq, 2020-01-23 18:03:32, 2020-01-23 18:03:32)) in file C:\wamp64\www\master-fullstack\api-rest-laravel\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connection.php on line 669

Y en la parte de codigo:

```php
//Validacion pasada correctamente 


$pwd= password_hash($params->password,PASSWORD_BCRYPT,['cost'=>4]);

//Crear usuario
$user = new User();
$user->name=$params_array['name'];                
$user->name=$params_array['surname'];
$user->name=$params_array['email'];
$user->name=$pwd;


//Guardar el usuario
$user->save();
```

No se donde puede estar el error, me dice que no tiene un valor por defecto

---

```
//Crear usuario
                $user = new User();
                $user->name=$params_array['name'];                
                $user->surname=$params_array['surname'];
                $user->email=$params_array['email'];
                $user->password=$pwd;
```

Comment: Puedes copiar la función del controlador donde haces ese insert?

Comment: Lo principal, es que esta dando un error al insertar el valor de la columna email, ya que esta al parecer viene vacia, y como no tiene un valor por defecto y probablemente es requerido, da el error mencionado

Comment: Para el caso de hash de la contraseña Laravel posee un helper llamado `bcrypt` que hace su uso muy simple, revisa [aquí](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/helpers#method-bcrypt)

Answer (score 0):

Le estas asignando todos los valores siempre a la misma propiedad del modelo User a `$user->name` en lugar de asignar a cada una de las propiedades, deberias de tener algo así:

```
$user = new User();

$user->name     = $params_array['name'];
$user->surname  = $params_array['surname'];
$user->email    = $params_array['email'];
$user->password = $pwd;

$user->save();
```

Fijate que cada parametro lo asignamos a su propiedad, si siempre lo asignamos a la misma estamos machacando el valor todo el rato que es lo que te esta sucediendo, que al final el objeto `$user` solo tiene valor la propiedad `$user->name`.